# SQL left join to remove duplicates

Tags: sql, join, teradata

I have the following data table:

Table:

```
ID    Event
A     1
A     ?
B     ?
```

I want to write a SQL query so that I can remove duplicate ID's with preference for actual values over '?'. I can also guarantee that the only duplicates are for IDs that have a regular event (value 1-9) as well as a '?' event. So in the case above, my query should return:

```
ID  Event
A   1
B   ?
```

I want my query to return the rows that match this description as well as all the columns for those rows. My attempt so far is a left join:

```
sel L.*
from table L
left join table R
on L.ID = R.ID and
(L.Event is null and R.Event is not null)
where R.ID is null
```

This seems to partially work. It's able to remove duplicates but somehow for the case where there is a non duplicate ID like B with a '?" event in the above example, that row is removed. However, there are other cases where the same case is kept.

Why is this happening? I would think that might join on condition is correct since I check for when

```
R.Event is not null
```

but something is evidently wrong in my logic. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: just simply add `GROUP BY id`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve this problem, but `left join` just doesn't come to mind.

How about this?

```
select t.*
from t
where event <> '?'
union all
select t.*
from t
where event = '?' and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.event <> '?');
```

For these values, you could also use `group by`:

```
select id, min(event)
from t
group by id;
```

But aggregation would not keep all the other values in the row.

Or, a general approach to such prioritization queries is `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id
                                order by (case when event = '?' then 1 else 2 end) desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```